How to read the forward slash from an Excel sheet using Python?
I have an excel sheet with 20+ columns. If I want to select a row that doesn't contain the text n/a, is it possible to pass n/a as text and find it?
The code which I tried is:
import pandas as pd
import re
import os

def extract_data(input_file):
    # Read the input Excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)

    # Check if 'agreed' is present in column 5
    if not df.iloc[:, 4].astype(str).str.contains('Agreed', case=False, na=False).any():
        print("No 'agreed' found in column 5")
        return

    # Filter rows where column 5 contains 'agreed'
    filtered_df = df[df.iloc[:, 4].astype(str).str.contains('Agreed', case=False, na=False)]

    # Initialize DataFrames for the four sheets
    volumen_df = pd.DataFrame()
    mrr_premium_df = pd.DataFrame()
    lrr_df = pd.DataFrame()
    meb_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Define a function to extract values from text
    def extract_values(text, pattern):
        match = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        return match.group(1) if match else None

    # Function to check if exclusion texts are in the specified column
    def contains_exclusion_texts(value):
        exclusion_texts = ["n/a", "entfallen", "tbd"]
        return any(excluded_text in str(value).lower() for excluded_text in exclusion_texts)

    # Process each row individually
    for index, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
        col13 = contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[13])
        col14 = contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[14])
        col15 = contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[15])
        
        pdu_short_name = str(row.iloc[11]).replace('FAULT_', '')
        cycle_time = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'(\d+\s*ms)')
        n_value = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'n\s*=\s*(\d+)')
        q_value = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'q\s*=\s*(\d+)')
        max_delta_counter = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'MaxDeltaCounterInit\s*=\s*(\d+)')
        no_new_or_repeated_data = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'NoNewOrRepeatedData\s*=\s*(\d+)')

        data = {
            'PDU short name': pdu_short_name,
            'Cycle time': cycle_time,
            'n': n_value,
            'q': q_value,
            'Max Delta Counter': max_delta_counter,
            'No New Or Repeated Data': no_new_or_repeated_data
        }

        if not col13:
            # Volumen
            volumen_df = volumen_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        if not col14 :
            # Check column 12 for LRR or MRR_Premium
            type_col_value = str(row.iloc[12])
            if 'LRR' in type_col_value:
                lrr_df = lrr_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            if 'MRR_Premium' in type_col_value:
                mrr_premium_df = mrr_premium_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
        if not col15 :
            # Meb
            meb_df = meb_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

    # Define output file path
    output_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(input_file), 'extracted_data3.xlsx')

    # Save the extracted data to a new Excel file with different sheets
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file) as writer:
        volumen_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Volumen', index=False)
        mrr_premium_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MRR Premium', index=False)
        lrr_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LRR', index=False)
        meb_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Meb', index=False)

    print(f"Data extracted and saved to {output_file}")

# Get the input file path from the user
input_file_path = input("Enter the path to your input Excel file: ")

# Call the function with the user-provided file path
extract_data(input_file_path)

In this code, I'm trying to find if n/a, entfallen, or tbd is present in the required columns, but I'm getting output for entfallen and tbd only, not for n/a. This means the code is not detecting n/a in any of the columns. What might be the reason? Because of the forward slash present in n/a, should I find an alternative approach to reading n/a instead of a string.

can you provide a minimal reproducible example with your input and expected output?

Column 5: Containing some values, including "Agreed".
Columns 13, 14, 15: Containing some exclusion texts ("n/a", "entfallen", "tbd") and other values.
Column 12: With some values like "LRR" and "MRR_Premium".
Column 20: Containing text with values like "100 ms", "n = 10", "q = 5", etc. Output: Volumen: Rows that have no exclusion texts in Column 13.
MRR Premium: Rows from Column 12 that have no exclusion texts in Column 14 and contain "MRR_Premium".
LRR: Rows from Column 12 that have no exclusion texts in Column 14 and contain "LRR".
Meb: Rows that have no exclusion texts in Column 15.

I tried recreating your logic to see what may be the issue. You seem to be sending one row at a time i.e., single values. However, it seems you want to check if any of the row values of the columns (13, 14, and 15) are "n/a","entfallen", or "tbd" in which case you want to return True if they exist in those column.
Instead of calling the contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[13]), contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[14]), contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[15])
from within the for loop, rather take them out and pass the entire column to the function like below example:
import pandas as pd

def contains_exclusion_texts(col1):
    print(col1)
    exclusion_texts = ["n/a", "entfallen", "tbd"]
    return any(excluded_text in str(col1).lower() for excluded_text in exclusion_texts)

# Creating the first Dataframe using dictionary
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3, 4],
                    "b":["n/a", 6, 7, 8]})

col_val = contains_exclusion_texts(df1.iloc[:,1])
print("Exclusion texts exists? ", col_val)

By passing all rows of a column (using .iloc[:,column_number]) to the any() function we check if the exclusion text provided exits in any of its rows and thus would return True or False. Hope this helps.


I tried this approch, but im getting same output where n/a is not found,  Now i am try to count using counter, whether the required txt is found or not. I got Correct output for entfallen and tbd but getting 0 for n/a (Indicates that n/a is not found)

import pandas as pd
import re
import os

def extract_data(input_file):
    # Read the input CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(input_file, keep_default_na=False)

    # Check if 'agreed' is present in column 5
    if not df.iloc[:, 4].astype(str).str.contains('Agreed', case=False, na=False).any():
        print("No 'agreed' found in column 5")
        return

    # Filter rows where column 5 contains 'agreed'
    filtered_df = df[df.iloc[:, 4].astype(str).str.contains('Agreed', case=False, na=False)]

    # Initialize DataFrames for the four sheets
    volumen_df = pd.DataFrame()
    mrr_premium_df = pd.DataFrame()
    lrr_df = pd.DataFrame()
    meb_df = pd.DataFrame()

    # Counters for exclusion texts
    n_a_counter = 0
    entfallen_counter = 0
    tbd_counter = 0

    # Define a function to extract values from text
    def extract_values(text, pattern):
        match = re.search(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE)
        return match.group(1) if match else None

    # Function to check if exclusion texts are in the specified column
    def contains_exclusion_texts(value):
        exclusion_texts = {
            "n/a": False,
            "entfallen": False,
            "tbd": False
        }
        value_str = str(value).strip().lower()
        for text in exclusion_texts:
            if text in value_str:
                exclusion_texts[text] = True
        return exclusion_texts

    # Process each row individually
    for index, row in filtered_df.iterrows():
        exclusion_results = {
            "n/a": False,
            "entfallen": False,
            "tbd": False
        }
        
        for col_index in [13, 14, 15]:
            exclusion_results = contains_exclusion_texts(row.iloc[col_index])

            if exclusion_results["n/a"]:
                n_a_counter += 1
                print(f"n/a found in PDU short name: {row.iloc[11]}")
                
            if exclusion_results["entfallen"]:
                entfallen_counter += 1
                print(f"entfallen found in PDU short name: {row.iloc[11]}")
                
            if exclusion_results["tbd"]:
                tbd_counter += 1

            pdu_short_name = str(row.iloc[11]).replace('FAULT_', '')
            cycle_time = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'(\d+\s*ms)')
            n_value = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'n\s*=\s*(\d+)')
            q_value = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'q\s*=\s*(\d+)')
            max_delta_counter = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'MaxDeltaCounterInit\s*=\s*(\d+)')
            no_new_or_repeated_data = extract_values(str(row.iloc[20]), r'NoNewOrRepeatedData\s*=\s*(\d+)')

            data = {
            'PDU short name': pdu_short_name,
            'Cycle time': cycle_time,
            'n': n_value,
            'q': q_value,
            'Max Delta Counter': max_delta_counter,
            'No New Or Repeated Data': no_new_or_repeated_data
            }

            if not (exclusion_results["n/a"]) and col_index == 13:
                # Volumen
                volumen_df = volumen_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            if not (exclusion_results["n/a"] or exclusion_results["entfallen"] or exclusion_results["tbd"]) and col_index == 14:
                # Check column 12 for LRR or MRR_Premium
                type_col_value = str(row.iloc[12])
                if 'LRR' in type_col_value:
                    lrr_df = lrr_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
                if 'MRR_Premium' in type_col_value:
                    mrr_premium_df = mrr_premium_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
            if not (exclusion_results["n/a"] or exclusion_results["entfallen"] or exclusion_results["tbd"]) and col_index == 15:
                # Meb
                meb_df = meb_df.append(data, ignore_index=True)

    # Define output file path
    output_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(input_file), 'extracted_data75.xlsx')

    # Save the extracted data to a new Excel file with different sheets
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file) as writer:
        volumen_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Volumen', index=False)
        mrr_premium_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='MRR Premium', index=False)
        lrr_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LRR', index=False)
        meb_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Meb', index=False)

    # Print counters
    print(f"Total n/a count: {n_a_counter}")
    print(f"Total entfallen count: {entfallen_counter}")
    print(f"Total tbd count: {tbd_counter}")

    print(f"Data extracted and saved to {output_file}")

# Get the input file path from the user
input_file_path = input("Enter the path to your input CSV file: ")

# Call the function with the user-provided file path
extract_data(input_file_path)   ''''     This code is recognizing the presence of n/a correctly, I am trying to modify this code to my original code, where it behaves seperately for seperate variants. 

